# Invalidating a `functools.cached_property`’s cache

Tags: python, caching, functools

I’m using `functools.cached_property` to store a long-lived session object like this:

```py
class Client:
    @cached_property
    def session(self):
        return service.login(...)
```

I want to invalidate the cache only in a very specific case, without giving up the convenience and clarity of `cached_property`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

`functools.cached_property` uses the same place where a regular instance attribute (`self.attr = ...`) would be stored: The object’s `.__dict__`! An invalidation method for your case would therefore look like:

```py
class Client:
    @cached_property
    def session(self):
        return service.login(...)

    def logout(self):
        self.__dict__.pop('session', None)
```

If you want to invalidate all `cached_property`s an object has, you can do this:

```py
def invalidate_cached_properties(obj):
    cls = type(obj)
    cached = {
        attr
        for attr in list(self.__dict__.keys())
        if (descriptor := getattr(cls, attr, None))
        if isinstance(descriptor, cached_property)
    }
    for attr in cached:
        del obj.__dict__[attr]
```